# How to view all active bits for a certain value?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

> Bitwise operators are those strange looking operators that may look hard to understand...

Well, they are not strange looking to me anymore but we're not best friends forever either. (Maybe in a far future).

While working with bitwise operators I often find myself wondering what bits are actually set. That made me wonder if PHP had some kind of function to view which bits are active for a certain value. I have googled around a bit but could not find any.

So my final question is: Is there a way to view all active bits for a certain number?

> What do you mean by active bits?

Using bitwise operators an integer is translated to a binary number.

An example:

```
16
00010000
35
00100011
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
var_dump(showBits(35));
```

This should return 1, 2 adn 6 because those are the active bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have to code your own function to do that, something like :

```
$val = 35;

$bitsVal = strrev(base_convert($val,10,2));

$activeBits = [];
foreach (str_split($bitsVal) as $key => $bit) {
  if ($bit == 1) $activeBits[] = $key; // $key + 1 depending on what you want 
}

print_r($activeBits);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0 // 1
    [1] => 1 // 2
    [2] => 5 // 6 with $key + 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, but you can convert a number into a binary representation as follows:

```
$n = 12345678;
$b = base_convert("$n",10,2);  // $b = "101111000110000101001110"
```

Note the quotation marks around `$n` — the `base_convert()` function expects the number to be passed as a string. The parameters `10` and `2` are the number bases you're converting between.

---

**EDIT**

Following your clarification, here's a function that converts an integer into an array of values corresponding to the nonzero bits:

```
function showBits($n) {
  $b = base_convert("$n",10,2);
  $a = array();
  for ($j=1,$i=strlen($b)-1;$i>=0;$j++,$i--) {
    if ($b[$i]=="1") $a[]=$j;
  }
  return $a;
}

// Example of use:
var_dump(showBits(35));
```